# What is the meaning of "intellectual life"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "intellectual life"? What is the context in which it is used? Can I use it in place of  "professional life" if I am an engineer?

Comment: I means doing/experiencing things which are intellectually stimulating, and which "stretch" the intellect.  If you're an engineer it isn't simply doing more engineering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Intellectual life" is the life of the [intellect](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/intellect), i.e. the life of thought, knowledge and ideas. That is not the same as "professional life" which is everything to do with your profession, much of which may not be related to thought or ideas.